# Blank screen while Yum updating and skipping

Tags: yum, automatic-updates

This question maybe is going to sound nonsensical and stupid but all these things are new to me and I'm always afraid that something is going to be wrong.

I recently started using CentOS and before I do any settings, I want to update my system.
The embarrassing thing is that when I call from console as root user

```
yum update
```

The system starts updating and said that it got 200 and more modules to update.
I confirm that I agree with that and the update process starts correctly.

On the screen I see the progress and after a while the screen goes blank, power saver turns it off.

When I hit any key on the keyboard, the screen goes on again but the current downloading transaction does not go to 100%; the update process simply goes to the next transaction.

Now I'm wondering what will happen with the transaction which is not finished until 100%.

Is that module going to be updated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS times out the screen by default on the console.  That's normal.  You shouldn't use enter as a means to wake it up, as it will put enter on the input buffer and the next time yum asks you for confirmation, you might be selecting a default option.

I think CentOS has a mouse driver, so wiggling the mouse to wake up the screen is a better approach.  Otherwise use a key like "a".  =)

Comment: Than You for pointing me to right direction about using enter and default option, But My basic question is What will happen whit updates which I interrupt by pressing a enter key. Will it be installed or not , and will it work fine as I accept

Comment: Well, you can check the outcome of a particular package with the rpm command, I believe rpm -q <packagename> will tell you the version number that is currently installed and you can compare it to the latest.